# ASP .Net Core RESTful App Deployed as Windows Service is not Working / Starting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, carter

I am working with some sort a small RESTful layer to expose (to the internet) the local application data in a host machine.

It behaves like a typical web service that listens incoming request to a port. I wrote it with ASP .NET Core 3.1 with a tiny layer wrapper called [Carter](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter), it has also a DLL / COM Reference (used for querying the data).

I followed the following guides to configure it as a windows service, publish the service, and then to create it.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio
- https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/21/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-app-as-a-windows-service-in-net-core-3/

I did successfully created a service but it won't start and windows is showing this error dialog.

[image: Windows Could Not Start]

I am relatively new to .NET development and I am not sure what's wrong here or how to fix this.

**Program.cs**

```cs
namespace Adapter
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
namespace Adapter
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup()
        {
            // load the env values during start up
            new Env().Load();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // interface binding for dependency injection
            services.AddSingleTonServices();

            // carter and routing services
            services.AddCarter();
            services.AddRouting();
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapCarter());
        }
    }
}
```

BTW My project is running correctly when you run or debug it in visual studio.

Any help or idea will be much appreciated.

Comment: @IanKemp I tried debugging it, it works fine when you run and debug in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion is the problem caused by the timeout after the particular request.

This error has many variants.You can read this article to try to solve:

[[Fix] Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/)

Alternatively, to resolve this issue, you can download the following registry fix for your operating system：

[Windows Search “Error 1053” Fix for Windows 7](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/archived/w7-wsearch-1053-fix.zip)

[Windows Search “Error 1053” Fix for Windows 8.1](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/archived/w8-wsearch-1053-fix.zip)

[Windows Search “Error 1053” Fix for Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/archived/w10-wsearch-1053-fix.zip)